# Compress and upload an image but the image is only green

Tags: javascript, reactjs, upload, multer, image-compression

I using Reactjs to build my app,I use https://github.com/alextanhongpin/compress.js library to compress before upload images, but sometimes the image uploaded to the server returns the image only in green color. And this happens only very rarely with some guests (I thought it was the client's device being too old so it was, but I tried devices on browserstack but no such case.
)
I also don't know if the problem is caused by image compression or is it really the customer's device
**here is the code**

```
import Compress from "compress.js";

export async function resizeImageFn(file, maxHeight = 600, maxWidth = 800) {
  const compress = new Compress();
  const resizedImage = await compress.compress([file], {
    size: 1, // the max size in MB, defaults to 2MB
    quality: 1, // the quality of the image, max is 1,
    maxWidth: maxWidth, // the max width of the output image, defaults to 1920px
    maxHeight: maxHeight, // the max height of the output image, defaults to 1920px
    resize: true, // defaults to true, set false if you do not want to resize the image width and height
  });
  const img = resizedImage[0];
  const base64str = img.data;
  const file2 = Compress.convertBase64ToFile(base64str, img.ext);

  // const resizedFiile = dataURLtoFile(base64str, file?.name);
  return file2;
}
```

**and then I switched to image compression using canvas like this :**

```
const resizeImgFnByCanvas = async (
  file_png,
  minHeight = 1200,
  minWidth = 2000,
  maxSize = 1.2,
  ext = "jpg"
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file_png);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      let image = document.createElement("img");
      image.src = e.target.result;
      image.onload = async function () {
        let canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
          width = image.width,
          height = image.height;
        let resizedFile = null;
        while (true) {
          height = height * 0.95;
          width = width * 0.95;
          canvas.width = width;
          canvas.height = height;
          canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
          let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL(`image/${ext}`);
          let resizedImage = dataURLToBlob(dataUrl);
          resizedFile = new File(
            [resizedImage],
            file_png?.name || `resizedPNG.${ext}`,
            {
              type: `image/${ext}`,
            }
          );

          if (
            resizedFile.size <= maxSize * 1024 * 1024 &&
            height < minHeight &&
            width < minWidth
          ) {
            break;
          }
        }
        resolve(resizedFile);
      };
    };
    reader.onerror = (e) => {
      reject(new Error("Cannot resize image"));
    };
  });
};
export default resizeImgFnByCanvas;
```

**Both methods work normally, but sometimes one of my customers has a case of green image uploading look like.**
[image: Green image]

**Note : I using Nestjs for BE to upload with multer**

I want my photos to always be uploaded in the best way, can someone tell me the cause of it or give me a library, another solution, thanks a lot.